# Issue in applying css in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I am working in Visual studio code in LWC. I am trying to apply CSS to headers of `lightning-datatable`

**HTML**
priceScreen.html

```
<lightning-datatable class= "table-test" data={accList} columns={columns} key-field="Id" selected-rows={selectedRows} >
</lightning-datatable>
```

**CSS**
priceScreen.css

```
.THIS .table-test thead th span { 
    background-color: #16325c; 
    color: white}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the CSS of the Lightning-Datatable directly inside the Lightning Web Component because of [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom).

There is a [workaround](https://getoncrm.com/how-to-override-css-of-inner-elements-of-lightning-web-component/) for this, but make sure you check [Overwrite standard lightning web component CSS by class name](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279878/overwrite-standard-lightning-web-component-css-by-class-name) before going for that.

---

Also the LWC CSS work in the exact same way the vanilla CSS does. So you don't need to mention the `.THIS` here. So your CSS should look like this. **Still, note that this will not be applicable outside the shadow tree, and apparently the datatable.**

```
.table-test thead th span { 
    background-color: #16325c; 
    color: white
}
```

Comment: I tried removing 'THIS', but its not working

Comment: @AthiraVenugopal as I mentioned it will not work due to shadow dom. Check the workaround mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, it worked using loadStyle(). But why the header color blinked out when hover over it? How can I avoid it?

Comment: No idea, try inspecting that.

Comment: Does anyone know if this will work in an embedded lightning web component ( i.e VF >> AuraAPP > lwc component)

Comment: it should work. try it. @Soji