Wrap text drop down on lightning:datatable not rendering properly
When i click on the drop down in my datatable the wrap-text/ clip text drop down opens inside the header and not over the header


This is the code for Data table:
<div class="data-table slds-is-relative forceListViewManagerGrid">
                            <lightning:datatable data="{!v.tableData}"
                                                 columns="{!v.columns}"
                                                 keyField="id"
                                                 showRowNumberColumn="true"
                                                 hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                                                 onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction}" />

Setting the columns:
 setColumns: function(component,event,helper){
        component.set('v.columns', [
            { label: 'Site Name', fieldName: 'siteName', type: 'text',wrapText: true},
            { label: 'Address', fieldName: 'address', type: 'text',wrapText: true},
            { label: 'Approximate Distance', fieldName: 'approximateDistance', type: 'text'},
            { label: 'Language', fieldName: 'language', type: 'text'},
            { label: 'Appointments Available', fieldName: 'OnlineAppointmentsAvailable', type: 'text'},
            { label: 'Appointment Required', fieldName: 'appointmentRequired', type: 'text'},// Added this coloum as part of 9138
            { label: '', type: 'button', initialWidth: 90, typeAttributes: 
             {
                 label: 'More', name: 'More', title: 'More' 
             }
            }
        ]);
    },  


Hi @Somyak Simant. Welcome to SFSE!. The wrap text menus are standard lightning datatable element whose opening depends on various things like viewport, container element of the datatable , custom component override stylings. Have you done any custom CSS to override this std. behavior? If so , please add that CSS which we can then analyze and provide any inputs. You can refer this answer on how to override std. Datatable stylings : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/322173/issue-in-applying-css-in-lightning-datatable

Hi @Sarang thank you for your reply was actually able to resolve this issue by adding some additional CSS changes
