# How to combine lightning-quick-action-panel and slds-modal_large?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, quickaction, modal, lightning-quickaction

I want to pop-up a modal LWC using a quick action, without any Aura components. This should be possible since Summer'21.

I am currently using an Aura component that does the pop-up and at the same time specifies the maximum size of the modal.

When specifying a LWC in a quick action, I cannot specify a size. So how can I do it? Because the default size is too small for me.

If I look at the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-quick-action-panel/documentation) on lightning-quick-action-panel, it states "The lightning-quick-action-panel component implements the Modals blueprint in the SLDS".

In that section, I see a demonstration of the slds-modal_large class and I would like to apply it to my modal, but I don't know how: slds-modal_large is not a class that can be applied to lightning-quick-action-panel. I want to use lightning-quick-action-panel because a) it is recommended and b) it gives a nice border for the modal.

Where and how in the CSS or HTML file do I combine lightning-quick-action-panel and slds-modal_large?

Comment: if you inspect the LWC quick action (or even standard quick actions), you'll see it has a wrapper around it that limits its width that you can't target/change (`uiModal--medium modal-container`) due to any styles you apply being [scoped](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css) to your component. I don't think there's a way without going around that (and will eventually not work) like the [loadStyle hack](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279878/overwrite-standard-lightning-web-component-css-by-class-name)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually possible to increase size of the quick action's modal using `loadStyle()` hacks.

You just need to create, or use the existing one, static resource with the CSS file which contains the following code:

```
.slds-modal__container {
  width: 95% !important;
  max-width: 95% !important;
}

.slds-modal__content {
  height: 100% !important;
  max-height: 95% !important;
}
```

Then you need to import it in your component and that's all, it will work without any problems.

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { loadStyle } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

import LargeQuickActionModal from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/LargeQuickActionModal";

export default class QuickActionWithLargeModal extends LightningElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
      loadStyle(this, LargeQuickActionModal + "/increaseModalSize.css")
    ]);
  }
}
```

---

By the way, you can also add the `slds-modal_large` class to where it should belong if you will load a js file from the static resource, that will find the modal in the DOM tree and add the class. But, I think in the context of the quick action's modal it won't work because it has some additional modifications and the class doesn't have any effect.

**Demo**
[image]