# How to increase length of dropdown for lightning-combobox in lightning web component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I am trying to show all of the picklist value in dropdown instead of using scrollbar. Is there any way we can set the lenght/height of the dropdown for lightning-combobox component in lightning web component where the scrollbar do not come.

[image]

My code:

Basic.html:

```html
 <template>
     <lightning-combobox
         name="progress"
         label="Status"
         value={value}
         placeholder="Select Progress"
         options={options}
         onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox>

      <p>Selected value is: {value}</p>
</template>
```

Basic.JS

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class ComboboxBasic extends LightningElement {
    value = 'inProgress';

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'New', value: 'new' },
            { label: 'In Progress', value: 'inProgress' },
            { label: 'Finished', value: 'finished' },
            { label: 'New1', value: 'new1' },
            { label: 'old', value: 'old' },
            { label: 'main', value: 'main' },
            { label: 'exclusive', value: 'exclusive' },
            { label: 'deployed', value: 'deployed' },
            { label: 'not use', value: 'not use' },
            { label: 'last', value: 'last' },
        ];
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.slds-dropdown-trigger_click .slds-dropdown {
    height: 1549px;
}
```

Using this style we can adjust the height. Add this to your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Do not override standard class directly. You should update using your custom class.

You need to add static resource for your CSS and include in component. Here `CustomCSS` is a static resource created. Added `statuscombobox` custom class on `lightning-combobox` so `css` will impact only on required component.

**basic.html File**

```
 <template>
     <lightning-combobox
         name="progress"
         label="Status"
         class="statuscombobox"
         value={value}
         placeholder="Select Progress"
         options={options}
         onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox>

      <p>Selected value is: {value}</p>
</template>
```

**basic.jsfile**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import CustomCSS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/CustomCSS';
export default class ComboboxBasic extends LightningElement {
    value = 'inProgress';

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'New', value: 'new' },
            { label: 'In Progress', value: 'inProgress' },
            { label: 'Finished', value: 'finished' },
            { label: 'New1', value: 'new1' },
            { label: 'old', value: 'old' },
            { label: 'main', value: 'main' },
            { label: 'exclusive', value: 'exclusive' },
            { label: 'deployed', value: 'deployed' },
            { label: 'not use', value: 'not use' },
            { label: 'last', value: 'last' },
        ];
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, CustomCSS)
        ]).then(() => {
        });
    }
}
```

**CustomCSS CSS File**

```
.statuscombobox .slds-dropdown-trigger_click .slds-dropdown {
    height: 350px;
}
```

[image: Status Combobox]

Answer (score -2):

Overwrite standard lightning web component CSS by class name.
then import in LWC Component and Use it

[Overwrite standard lightning web component css by class name](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279878/overwrite-standard-lightning-web-component-css-by-class-name)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm

Comment: Hi Nilay, could you explain this a little bit more? The first link you provided has an accepted answer that states that overwriting is impossible. The second link you provided is only regarding Experience Cloud. So what exactly do you suggest?