# Is there any way to make lwc dual picklist component border different color

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css

I have requirement where on condition i want to change the border color for `lightning-dual-listbox` . I am trying to override `.slds-dueling-list__options` with border color , but its not working

https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/I7gYGC1ReNcHWBPvpuCp/src/app.css?p=stories

When i inspect and manipulate it works, but the same when i try to add it to css , it is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't reliably manipulate SLDS classes and expect them to work in closed components (e.g. anything starting with `lightning-*`). This is because of the concept of CSS isolation, explained in the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_dom) documentation.

> CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child. In our example, a p style defined in the todoApp.css style sheet doesn’t style the p element in the c-todo-item component, because the styles don’t reach into the shadow tree. See CSS.

There is a very old trick of doing [manipulation using loadStyle](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/291929/2984), but this only works in a synthetic Shadow DOM. If you need this level of functionality, copy the cross-compiled components from [base-components-recipes](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes), and you'll have full control to modify those components as you desire. Also, context matters: this is only a limitation of Salesforce because of how CSS is loaded. If you're writing a LWR (Lightning Web Runtime) app in something like Heroku, you can add styles to the global style sheets and they'll work as you expect.

Comment: ok sfdc fox.. i was also trying at changing label name.. but it seems not possible.